# Debian cron cannot find /var/backups after accidentally moving /var

Tags: linux, debian, email, cron, mailutils

I'm dumb and accidentally moved everything in /var to a subdirectory of the root directory. I realized my mistake and moved it back, but now I'm getting this weird error mailed to me every morning:

```
/etc/cron.daily/dpkg: 6: cd: can't cd to /var/backups
```

The weirdest thing about the entire issue is that these mails are addressed to root, but they go to my user account, which is a sudoer but not root. These errors only started showing up once I installed mailutils, so they may have been occurring for a while, so I would like to know if I broke something important by moving files or if this error is harmless.

**Edit**:

Output of `ls -laZ /var`:

```
total 864
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  ?   4096 Apr  4 18:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root  ?   4096 Apr  4 18:59 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?  81920 Apr  4 07:37 alternatives.tar.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?   1789 Apr  3 16:14 alternatives.tar.1.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?  24407 Apr  3 21:48 apt.extended_states.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?   1739 Apr  3 16:52 apt.extended_states.1.gz
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root  ?   4096 Apr  8 17:34 cache
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?      0 Apr  4 07:37 dpkg.arch.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?     32 Apr  3 16:14 dpkg.arch.1.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?    422 Apr  3 16:17 dpkg.diversions.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?    168 Apr  3 16:14 dpkg.diversions.1.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?    135 Apr  3 16:17 dpkg.statoverride.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?    120 Apr  3 15:57 dpkg.statoverride.1.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ? 603418 Apr  3 21:48 dpkg.status.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  ?  95138 Apr  3 16:14 dpkg.status.1.gz
drwxr-xr-x 34 root root  ?   4096 Apr  8 17:34 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff ?   4096 Mar 19 09:46 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  ?      9 Apr  3 15:52 lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  ?   4096 Apr  8 17:34 log
drwxrwsrwt  2 root mail  ?   4096 Apr  9 08:18 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  ?   4096 Apr  3 15:52 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root  ?      4 Apr  3 15:52 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  ?   4096 Apr  8 17:34 spool
drwxrwxrwt  4 root root  ?   4096 Apr  9 08:09 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  ?   4096 Apr  4 18:59 www
```

Output of `ls -laZ /var/backups`:

```
ls: cannot access '/var/backups': No such file or directory
```

Comment: When you moved the files, how did you do it? It sounds like the permissions for `/var/backups/`, and maybe for `/var/` itself, have been altered in such a way that `dpkg` is unable to `cd` into that directory anymore. Could you run `ls -laZ /var/` and `ls -laZ /var/backups/` and paste the results?

Comment: @PrestonManess I added the info you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the directory `/var/backups` does not exist. You should be able to re-create it though, with the proper permissions and ownership:

`sudo -u root mkdir -p -m="00755" "/var/backups"`

After that, you should be able to `ls -laZ /var/backups/` and get a result back (even if the directory is empty).

Comment: After doing that I get: 
`total 8`
`drwxr-xr-x  2 root root ? 4096 Apr 10 14:41 .`
`drwxr-xr-x 12 root root ? 4096 Apr 10 14:41 ..`